# when issuing a logout command to my cpanel ftp server, it returns a 500 error unknown command

Tags: java, cpanel, ftp4j

I am using **it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j** with a cpanel server and when I try to close the connection, I am getting a 500 error: unknown command. I assume that means that the cpanel ftp server is using a different command but I don't know how to issue the proper command to close the ftp connection or even what that command is.

I am aware of abruptlyCloseCommunication() but I would prefer a clean and proper method for closing connections.

Comment: Did you get solution, i m also facing same error, pls help. there is not quit command.

Comment: Yes, that is why there's an accepted solution, DOH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

abruptlyCloseCommunication() method causes the communication channel to be abruptly closed.  It is gives as an "emergency brake" to close the control connection when it is blocked. A thread-safe solution for the same purpose is a call to disconnect(false).

Instead you can use client.disconnect(true); class, This one sends the FTP QUIT command to the remote server, requesting a legal disconnect procedure. Hope it will also work for cpanel.